# Is there a way in flutter to make an Asset from an Image I got from imagePicker?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, image, assets

I want to plot multiple assets with buildGridView. I already have some assets to plot. But I want to add to this asset list some images I'm getting from using imagePicker. I'd like to ask if it is possible to make these images (from imagePicker) assets so I can also add them to the list and plot with buildGridView.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what is said on assets in the [Flutter documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/assets-and-images):

> Flutter apps can include both code and assets (sometimes called
> resources). **An asset is a file that is bundled** and deployed with your
> app, and is accessible at runtime. [...]

So no, you won't be able to add any assets once your application is compiled. If you want to use images from an image picker you will need to use workaround such as reading the file's bytes (you could use the widget `Image.memory`). The package image_picker (which I suppose is the one you are using) provide a method `readAsBytes()` for the retrieved file.

```dart
final myImage = await pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

if (myImage != null) {
  final myImageBytes = await myImage.readAsBytes();  
  return Image.memory(myImageBytes);
}
```

### Documentation

- [Image.memory](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.memory.html)
- [image_picker readAsBytes](https://pub.dev/documentation/cross_file/latest/cross_file/XFile/readAsBytes.html)